# Generate a unique metadescription for each product

Tags: ruby-on-rails, metadata

I'm trying to generate a different metadescription for each product in my database. A product can have several values (nearly all values are stored as arrays).

Show.html.erb

```
<% if @product.about.nil? %>
  <% meta_description "#{@product.name} #{@product.type.join(" ")}
  #{@product.location.join(" ")} #{@product.market.join(" ")} 
  {@product.material.join(" ")}" %>
<% else %>
  <% meta_description "#{@product.about}" %>
<% end %>
```

I get the following error:

```
undefined method `join' for nil:NilClass
```

And this is because a specific product has no values for `#{@product.market.join(" ")}` and `#{@product.material.join(" ")}`. For products that do have these values, there is no error. How can I solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `@product.material.join(" ")` to `@product.material.try(:join, " ")`.

Also, if it were me, I'd move all of that logic out of the view and into a helper or an instance method on @product.

Example instance method:

```
class Product << ActiveRecord::Base

  def meta_description
    if about.present?
      about
    else
      "#{name} #{type.try(:join, ' ')} #{location.try(:join, ' ')} #{market.try(:join, ' ')} {material.try(:join, ' ')}"
    end
  end

end
```

And then in the view:

```
<% meta_description @product.meta_description %>
```

Comment: Thanks Philip. Works like a charm. I'm a rails newbie. Any chance you can show me how you would put the logic into a helper?

Comment: @mini I've updated my answer to include an instance method example.  Helper would be similar, but you'd obviously need to pass in the product.